# Create new polygon from area bounded between two existing layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am trying to create a new polygon layer made up of the area of an existing polygon layer south of another layer that bisects it. This is a little difficult to explain, so here is a screenshot that I hope helps:

[image: bounded region]

There is a river layer (gray) that bisects the county layer (blue). I want to create a new polygon in QGIS that includes all of the county area south of the river layer. Both layers are polygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could:

1. Run Difference (county as input and river as overlay)
2. Run Multipart to Singlepart on the result
3. Delete the unwanted part of the Multipart-To-Singlepart-Result